# I have 16 features or terms and a maximum degree of 5 , how do I form unique polynomials , what is the number of unique polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A number of possible combinations out of 16 variables and degree of polynomial being 5?

Combinations: If I have 16 variables and the max number of polynomial degrees is 5(i.e, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are included), how many possible unique combinations of polynomials can I form?

To begin with, I started with unique combinations of 16 variables which is 2^n = 65536, now when the polynomial degree is involved how will the number of unique combinations increase, i am out of ideas.

Comment: to begin with, i started with the number of possible unique combinations of the 16 terms with is 2^16 = 65536 but when the degree of the polynomials gets involved i tend to lose my mind

Comment: even a formula would help

Comment: $2^{16*5}$? Possibly multiplied by 2 for a constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 16 variables, call them $a,b,...,p$. Each can be degree 1,2,3,4, or 5. So these are the possible terms in your polynomial:

$a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5\\b, b^2, b^3, b^4, b^5\\...\\p, p^2,p^3,p^4,p^5$

of which there are $5*16=80$ of them.

Since each can be included or not included in the polynomial, you get $2^{80}=1.208926e+24$ possible polynomials. If you include the possibility of including a constant, you'd multiply this number by 2.

Comment: Thank you so very much, but just to ask does it also incude the terms like a,p2,c3 etc.

Comment: Also it would be kind of you to say what the constant means here and why would we multiply this by 2